# How to subtract one minute from column in mysql database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5

I am Trying to subtract 1 minute from duration column through update query but it is not working. Duration field is of type time.

I try to use minus sign with new value but it is not working.

```
public function index()
{
    $current = Carbon::now('Asia/Karachi');

    Sale::where('date','=',$current->toDateString())
        ->where('time','<=',$current->toTimeString())
        ->update(['duration' => '- 00:01:00']);
}
```

I want to subtract one minute with help of this query.

Comment: `$current->subMinute()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use `DATE_SUB`?

Something like

```
$object->update(['duration' => DB::raw('DATE_SUB(duration, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)')])
```

I don't have a laravel instance in front of my, but that's how I'd write the SQL query and I think that's right based off my laravel memory.

Comment: let me try this one